# Use UWP methods from .Net Standard library

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I know there is a way to use UWP methods from WPF apps.

My question is whether there is a way to use those methods from a .Net Standard library. Just adding the references mentioned [here](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/) doesn't help. It doesn't recognize them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Individual Platforms (.NET Framework, .NET Core, UWP, Mono) can reference .NET Standard libraries. But .NET Standard libraries cannot reference other libraries built specifically for a platform (.NET Framework, UWP etc).

Which makes sense since .NET Standard libraries themselves are supposed to be platform agnostic, so you shouldn't be able to add a library that would only work on a single platform.